# Strange behaviour of sscanf with string

Tags: c, scanf

I've got a trouble with `sscanf`. To check it I made a simple file, so when I compile this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    char *a;
    /* */
    char *s = "GET /something HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    printf("sscanf: %d\n", sscanf(s, "GET %s HTTP", a));
    printf("a: %s\n", a);
    /* */
    printf("sscan: %d\n", sscanf("GET /more HTTP/1.1\r\n", "GET %s HTTP", a));
    printf("a: %s\n", a);
}
```

I get right output:

```
sscanf: 1
a: /something
sscan: 1
a: /more
```

But when I comment lines between empty comments sings, I get:

```
sscan: 0
a: (null)
```

**Question 1**: How can it be so?

And a little more: if I write `char *a = NULL`, I get:

```
sscanf: 0
a: (null)
sscan: 0
a: (null)
```

**Question 2**: Why?

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for `a`, so the `sscanf` is undefined behaviour. Why it pretends to work in the first case can only be determined by investigating the compiler output.

Comment: Some explanations: first I have a problem (Q2), problem (Q1) came when I checked (Q2). This problem don't let me to use options `-Werror -Wall` without `#pragma GCC diagnostic …`

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks, I've read man badly!

Comment: My man page says :"**s**    Matches  a  sequence of non-white-space characters; _the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input  sequence and the terminating null byte_ ('\0'), which is added automatically.  The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first." (italics added by me). All poointers passed to the `scanf` family must point to valid memory, although some extensions allow to request allocation with an additional `a` (or `m`), `%as` then.

Comment: @DanielFischer: the `a` option doesn't seem to work anymore with glibc, even when C89 is selected (contrary to the man page). `m` is fine though.

Comment: @teppic Aha. My man page mentions `m` only in the "Notes" section, and `a` in the main section. I've never used either.

Answer (score 5):

You're copying a string to an uninitialised pointer (`a`). You need to allocate storage for it (with `malloc`), or declare an array.

Implementations can sometimes appear to work correctly when you don't allocate any storage. When you assign NULL to `a`, `sscanf` fails to store anything, and so you try to print a "string" with a NULL pointer (which `printf` prints as `(null)` ). On some systems, your program would simply crash.

There is a compiler/library extension that allows automatic allocation of strings, but obviously this is not portable and not all compilers support it.

```
char *a;
scanf("%ms", &a;) // allocates storage for a
```

You can pass an uninitialised pointer to the function, but note the `&`.

Comment: Why is this not in the C99std? Seems extremely useful to me (especially for receiving information over a network). Whats the downfall of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing uninitialized pointer to sscanf. change `char *a;` to `char a[100]` and it should work correctly.

Comment: `man sscanf` says, that there is a modifier "%as" which dynamically allocates memory, but it doesn't work. Preallocating memory is bad thing because it should be as much as buffer in which I search substring.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing data to unallocated space. `char *a;` is only a pointer to random memory. After you try to put  data in your "string" you invoke undefined behavior and anything could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only right thing in my case, as I think, would be this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){
    char *s = strdup("GET /something HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    char *a, *e, *ans;
    char *end = s + strlen(s);
    a = strstr(s, "GET");
    if(!a) return -1;
    a += 4;
    if(a >= end) return -1;
    e = strstr(a, "HTTP/1.1");
    if(!e) return -1;
    *(--e) = 0;
    ans = strdup(a);
    printf("ans: %s\n", ans);
}
```

In common case string `s` can have a very large size, so it would be better not to allocate much memory, but allocate right so, as I need.

Case with "%as" doesn't work with my gcc (4.7.2).

Comment: You can use `m` instead -- I've put an example in my answer.

Comment: It didn't work. Now I try it: really, if you say `sscanf("GET more here", "GET %ms", &x);` it works! But first time I forgot an ampersand and got wrong result.

Comment: Yes -- that's because `sscanf` needs to change the pointer to the new memory, so it needs the `&`.